# ASP.NET IsMobileBrowser detection with Browser.Mobile file Wrong Detection with Sea Monkey

Tags: asp.net, mobile, browser-detection

I am using Request.Browser.IsMobileDevice in conjunction with the MDBF file that goes in the App_Browsers/Devices folder (http://mdbf.codeplex.com/)

Now using Sea Monkey browser (latest version 2.0.7) IsMobileDevice returns true.  Why might this be the case as clearly Sea Monkey is not a mobile browser.  In fact, I had the understanding it used a lot of the same core as FireFox (which does not return true)

Any insight on this?

Answer (score 0):

[mdbf was his last release](http://mdbf.codeplex.com/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=219552). I think you should change mdbf for wurfl, for example using 51degrees api.